# Some issues with fmincon in matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization

I was using Matlab's fmincon but the optimization stopped with the following message

```
fmincon stopped because the size of the current step is less than
the selected value of the step size tolerance.
```

I have TolX set to 10^-10 and Tolfun to 10^-10 as well

I checked the logs and the first-order optimality was 198. Therefore this is definitely not the optimum solution. What could possibly go wrong?

Further, I used different version of matlab R2013b and R2014a and for the same code and data, they have different results. Is there something wrong with fmincon in matlab R2013b?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided code to show us what you're doing. "they have different results." – how were they different? Was 2014a still bad?

Answer (score 1):

When you have a question about the difference between two versions of Matlab or, as in this case, two toolbox versions, the first place to check is release notes: [for Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html) and [for the Optimization toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/release-notes.html). Indeed, it seems that [`fmincon`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html) [was updated](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/release-notes.html#bt612yl-2). Do you specify an `'Algorithm'`? If not, the difference may be due the different default in R2014a. In this case, you may be able to specify the use of the `'interior-point'` algorithm in R2013b and get better results.

You can read about the algorithms used by `fmincon` [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/choosing-a-solver.html#bsbwxm7).